# Is There any Similar "Synchronized Method of Java" in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, synchronized

I need to execute one specific function in NodeJs one by one so that concurrent 
 requests dont enter into the same method parallely.

HOw can i implement java like method

```
 public synchronized void aaa() {
 }
```

in nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript / Node.js runs all user code in a single thread, hence basically your functions do not run in parallel. However, when you use asynchronous calls inside of your functions, they may run interwoven, i.e. although they still run in a single thread, the order may be different from what you expect.

For a more specific answer, your question must be way more specific.

Comment: Hello Mr Golo Roden, i updated the title of question